# dialogflow_grpc does not satisfy the required Kotlin Gradle plugin version

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, maven

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8tS5.png)

(i tried to change different version but the error still same)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  project ':dialogflow_grpc' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very outdated package `dialogflow_grpc` which was last updated 2-3 years ago and has a pub score of 80/140.

`dialogflow_grpc` needs to upgrade the "Kotlin Gradle plugin" version.

Usually, you could create a PR to fix this in the same package but it seems like this package is abandoned by the author.

I'd recommend looking for a different package that does the same thing or fork this package from [GitHub](https://github.com/savelee/dialogflow_grpc_flutter), updating the package, and publishing this package from your account by changing the name a bit.